# header("Location: ") is not working when upload audio file

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on upload audio file. Here header("Location:") is not working when upload audio file, but when upload image, that time header("Location:") is working fine.

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $action_link; ?>" method="post" id="form_category_profile" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
</form>
```

**Action Code**

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit'] == "Add") {

    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj->CONN, $_REQUEST['title']);

    if($_FILES['title']['name'] != ''){

        $tmp_name = $_FILES["title"]["tmp_name"];
        $audio_name = $_FILES["title"]["name"];
        $prefix = date("YmdHis");
        $audio_arr = $generalfuncobj->genfile_uploadFile($audio_path, $tmp_name, $audio_name, $prefix);
        $audio_new_name = $audio_arr[0];
        $audio->settitle($audio_new_name);
    }
    $audio->setstatus($status);
    $insert = $audio->insert();

    $_SESSION['msg'] = "Audio has been added successfully.";
    header("Location:index.php?file=audio_list");
    exit();
}
```

Using image file upload, here header("Location:") is working perfect, but when use audio file that time stop script before header("Location:").

Comment: What output do you get ? Any error messages ?

Comment: try echo "<script type='text/javascript'>  window.location='index.php?file=audio_list'; </script>";

Comment: @Vasil Shaddix No, there are no any display error message.

Comment: @Dave Same above problem using <script>

Comment: Are you submitting the file using ajax or normal form ?

Comment: `if ($_FILES['title']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['title']['error']);
}`  check the error with this code

Comment: When upload image file, that time header, <script> all are working perfect.

Comment: @Vasil Shaddix I have used normal form.

Comment: @VivekSingh Singh - There are nothing display any error, uploaded audio inserted in database as well as in project folder.

Comment: @VivekSingh Using this if ($_FILES['title']['error']){ } - There are display 0 means There is no error, the file uploaded with success.

Comment: Is it changing your url ?

Comment: @Vasil Shaddix No, there are no any changing url.

Comment: Can you please add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning of the script, to see if there are any error outputs ?

Comment: @Vasil Shaddix Hello, there are display no any error! Now i can't understand what is the problem is there.

Comment: Now, when i'm viewing "Page Source", there are display of "Audio Listing" functionality, but in url, there are display url of "Action File".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used write some line in `.htaccess` file. Using this, it is working fine.

**Script**

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10800
php_value max_input_time         10800
php_value max_execution_time     10800
php_value upload_max_filesize    110M
php_value post_max_size          120M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "index.php?file=audio_list";
</script>
<?php
```

Try this.

Comment: For audio upload, there are stop script before window.location. I tried so much using above and using header location. But still not any get solutions.

Comment: Check in Php.ini file the upload size and also check format allowed of the audio in code

Comment: I'll check in php.ini.

Comment: Hello @Naveed Ramzan,
I have changed upload_max_filesize and max_file_uploads in php.ini, but still issue is going.

Comment: have you restarted server ? 
If yes Then check in that php file by writing echo ini_get('upload_file_max'); and check what its showing ... old one or new one. ?

Comment: Hey, using echo ini_get('upload_file_max'); there are display nothing. It's empty.

Comment: ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); I apologize, i just wrote what I wanted to ask.